# Updating a table with Latin charset from a Unicode charset

Tags: teradata

I am trying to update a table with latin charset (in my target) from the source table which is unicode in charset.
I am getting an error like "string contains untranslatable characters".
I then deleted the table and changed the characters set to latin but the same error came while reinserting data in this.

What can i do in this scenario?
below is my update..

```
update AM1 from  DB1.AM_7541 AM1,
(sel  
distinct TRIM(SB.BUILDING_NAME) NEID, 
trim( leading '0' from sb.MAN) LCDMNO,
AM.Netw_equip,
LAST_TRANSACTION_DATE,
DISCONNECT_DATE,
SEQUENCE_NUMBER
from DB1.PLTL SB
inner join DB1.AM_7541 AM
on  trim( leading '0' from sb.MAN)=AM.AM_NUM
where (SB.LAST_TRANSACTION_DATE,trim(sb.MAN),SB.SEQUENCE_NUMBER)
in  ( sel max(LAST_TRANSACTION_DATE),trim(MAN) lcdmno,max(cast(SEQUENCE_NUMBER as integer))
from DB1.PLTL 
where DISCONNECT_DATE ='2500-01-01 00:00:00' and trim(lcdmno) not like '' 
and lcdmno is not null    
group by lcdmno
)
and TRIM(SB.BUILDING_NAME) not like ''
and DISCONNECT_DATE ='2500-01-01 00:00:00'
) der
set Netw_equip=der.NEID
where AM1.AM_NUM=der.lcdmno
```

My table DB1.PLTL is the source table with unicode character set and DB1.AM_7541 has latin character set.

Thanks.
Amit

Answer (score 2):

Since your source is unicode, you would be best off using unicode for both tables.  If you can't do that, you can use `translate`:
select
...

```
translate(<your latin column> USING UNICODE_TO_LATIN)
```

Keep in mind that not all unicode characters will translate to latin, so you may get errors.  If you do, you can put some ugly case statement together using [TRANSLATE_CHK](http://www.info.teradata.com/htmlpubs/DB_TTU_14_00/index.html#page/SQL_Reference/B035_1145_111A/String_Ops_Funcs.084.287.html).  But you'd  be much better off using unicode everywhere.

Comment: Or you can use `translate(<your latin column> USING UNICODE_TO_LATIN WITH ERROR)` which will replace all the non-translatable characters with SUB (substitute) character.

Comment: I prefer to use `translate_chk` with a case statement to control what I replace the untranslatable characters with.  But `translate... with error` should certainly work as well.

Comment: one of my field is a decimal and one is date_time. Do i need to translate that also?

Comment: No, translate is only for string data